# Adding arrows and label to the tikz diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to reproduce the picture below:
[image]
I have managed to come up with the axes, intersecting dashed lines and colored circles. What I have failed to do is to add the arrows, placing the label `\theta` and placing the 2 tikzpictures side by side. Below is my output based on what I have tried:
[image]
Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
        \draw [->, ultra thick, gray](0,-6)--(0,6) node[right,font=\fontsize {12}
        {12}\selectfont]{Factor 1};
        \draw [->,ultra thick, gray](-6,0)--(6,0) node[above,font=\fontsize {12}
        {12}\selectfont]{Factor 2};
        \draw[densely dashed,red] (6,-2)--(-6,2);
        \draw[densely dashed,red] (-1.3,-4)--(2,5);
        \foreach \Point in {(1.5,3), (.56,3.1), (1.2,3.7), (1.68,4), (.62,4.2), (1, 4.2)}{
            \node[blue] at \Point {\textbullet};
        }
        
        \foreach \Point in {(3.5,-2), (5.56,-2.1), (5.2,-1.7), (3.68,-2), (4.62,-2.2), (6, -2.2),(6,-1.5)}{
            \node[green] at \Point {\textbullet};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
        \draw [->, ultra thick, gray](0,-6)--(0,6) node[right,font=\fontsize {12}
        {12}\selectfont]{Factor 1};
        \draw [->,ultra thick, gray](-6,0)--(6,0) node[above,font=\fontsize {12}
        {12}\selectfont]{Factor 2};
        \draw[densely dashed,red] (-6,-2)--(7.3,2);
        \draw[densely dashed,red] (-.7,-5.5)--(2,5);
        
        \foreach \Point in {(1.5,3), (.56,3.1), (1.2,3.7), (1.68,4), (.62,4.2), (1, 4.2)}{
            \node[blue] at \Point {\textbullet};
        }
        
        \foreach \Point in {(3.5,2), (5.56,2.1), (5.2,1.7), (3.68,2), (4.62,2.2), (6, 2.2),(6,1.5)}{
            \node[green] at \Point {\textbullet};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are stubs of answer that should get you were you want. First, know that there are many more ways to achieve the desired display with different complexity/flexibility.

Because you are using absolute positioning, I will try to add as little as needed:

1. \theta:
   It is simply the node with this syntax

`\node at(0.5,1.5) {$\theta$};`.

Change the coordinate as you wish.

2. The arrows are plotted by a `to` path from sec 74.3 of the [manual](https://tikz.dev/library-edges#tikz/curve:to) .

`\draw [thick,->] (0,6)  to [out = -10, in = 120] (2,5);`

With `in` and `out` being angles on arrival and departure respectively in nodes.

3. for multiple tikzpictures, there are multiple ways.. Here is the straightforward one (not the best, IMHO). Just surround your tikz environment with a resizebox like this:

```latex
\resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    ...
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
```

In the end, here is what the code looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
\resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
%   \helpgrid
    \draw [->, ultra thick, gray](0,-6)--(0,6) node[right,font=\fontsize {12}
    {12}\selectfont]{Factor 1};
    \draw [->,ultra thick, gray](-6,0)--(6,0) node[above,font=\fontsize {12}
    {12}\selectfont]{Factor 2};
    \draw[densely dashed,red] (6,-2)--(-6,2);
    \draw[densely dashed,red] (-1.3,-4)--(2,5);
    \foreach \Point in {(1.5,3), (.56,3.1), (1.2,3.7), (1.68,4), (.62,4.2), (1, 4.2)}{
        \node[blue] at \Point {\textbullet};
    }
    
    \foreach \Point in {(3.5,-2), (5.56,-2.1), (5.2,-1.7), (3.68,-2), (4.62,-2.2), (6, -2.2),(6,-1.5)}{
        \node[green] at \Point {\textbullet};
    }


    % to help with the placement 
    \draw (0,0) grid (6,6);
    % adding arrows
    \draw [thick,->] (0,6)  to [out = -10, in = 120] (2,5);
    % placing theta
    \node at(0.5,1.5) {$\theta$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
    \draw [->, ultra thick, gray](0,-6)--(0,6) node[right,font=\fontsize {12}
    {12}\selectfont]{Factor 1};
    \draw [->,ultra thick, gray](-6,0)--(6,0) node[above,font=\fontsize {12}
    {12}\selectfont]{Factor 2};
    \draw[densely dashed,red] (-6,-2)--(7.3,2);
    \draw[densely dashed,red] (-.7,-5.5)--(2,5);
    
    \foreach \Point in {(1.5,3), (.56,3.1), (1.2,3.7), (1.68,4), (.62,4.2), (1, 4.2)}{
        \node[blue] at \Point {\textbullet};
    }
    
    \foreach \Point in {(3.5,2), (5.56,2.1), (5.2,1.7), (3.68,2), (4.62,2.2), (6, 2.2),(6,1.5)}{
        \node[green] at \Point {\textbullet};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

For this result:
[image: 2 graphs with arrows and theta]

I am sure you can fill in the blanks and complete your drawing.
PS: drew a grid to help me position the node.

Answer (score 1):

With use of Ti*k*Z libraries `angles`, `intersections` and `quotes`, and `arrows.meta` for nicer arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta,
                intersections,
                quotes}
\tikzset{
              > = Straight Barb,
ANG/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw, <-, thick,
                  angle radius = #1,
                  angle eccentricity=#2},
     arr/.style = {->, thick, gray}
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\draw [arr, name path=Y] 
            (0,-5) -- (0,5) coordinate (y) [label=righ:Factor 1];
\draw [arr] (-6,0) -- (7,0) coordinate (x) [label=Factor 1];
%
\draw[densely dashed, red,
      name path=R]  (-6,2) -- (7,-2.4) 
                    (-1.3,-4)--(2,5) coordinate (R1);
\foreach \Point in {(1.5,3), (.56,3.1), (1.2,3.7), (1.68,4), (.62,4.2), (1, 4.2)}
{
    \node[blue] at \Point {\textbullet};
}
\foreach \Point in {(3.5,-2), (5.56,-2.1), (5.2,-1.7), (3.68,-2), (4.62,-2.2), (6, -2.2),(6,-1.5)}
{
    \node[green] at \Point {\textbullet};
}
\draw[name intersections ={of=Y and R, by=O}]
     pic [ANG=10mm/0.75, "$\theta$"]  {angle=R1--O--y};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\draw [arr, name path=Y]
            (0,-5) -- (0,5) coordinate (y) [label=righ:Factor 1];
\draw [arr] (-6,0) -- (7,0) coordinate (x) [label=Factor 1];
%
\draw[densely dashed, red,
      name path=R]  (-1,-5) -- (2,5) coordinate (R2)
                    (-6,-2) -- (7,2.4);

\foreach \Point in {(1.5,3), (.56,3.1), (1.2,3.7), (1.68,4), (.62,4.2), (1, 4.2)}{
    \node[blue] at \Point {\textbullet};
}

\foreach \Point in {(3.5,2), (5.56,2.1), (5.2,1.7), (3.68,2), (4.62,2.2), (6, 2.2),(6,1.5)}{
    \node[green] at \Point {\textbullet};
}
\draw[name intersections ={of=Y and R, by=O}]
     pic [ANG=17mm/0.85, "$\theta$"]  {angle=R2--O--y};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

Comment: Thanks Zarko, can you kindly make some adjustments to the diagram on the right margin.

Comment: @itc, what adjustment?

Comment: The intersection point of the 2 densely dashed lines on the right hand diagram. Kindly see the right hand diagram I wish to reproduce on the question.

Comment: @itc, oh, this is problem? This you should do yourself! For example by trials and errors method : -).  From basic geometry is evident that you only need to change accordingly the start coordinate of this line . See if my guessing  `(-6,-2.4) -- (7,2.4)` is what you after ...